How to use common flyway migration files for both mysql and h2
I am using h2 database for testcase and mysql database as main DB.
Do I able to maintain single flyway migration for both.
I am using springboot framework.
application-mysql.properties:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shipment-planning?useSsl=true
spring.datasource.username=root

spring.flyway.default-schema=shipment-planning
spring.flyway.enabled=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.flyway.locations = h2/db/migration

application-h2.properties
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations = h2/db/migration

one of syntax error I got when I run with Mysql.properties

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATA TYPE TEXT' at line 2"



Use application-mysql.yml for MySQL(for main app) and application-h2.yml for H2 during testing, with shared Flyway migration scripts located in classpath:db/migration.    2. Activate the appropriate profile (mysql or h2) using spring.profiles.active in your application or test configuration.


Ya, I already do like that, when I go with application-h2.properties it works, but when I use application-mysql.properties, I got some syntax error.

Can you share those for the reference?

@SamPaulIsaac I edited in description, please refer that. Or let me know , if you look for someting else.

Looks like, the error is related to the differences between H2 Database and MySQL in handling SQL syntax. Make sure SQL scripts in the db/migration directory are compatible with both H2 and MySQL.  I doubt the issue lies here - MySQL does not have a DATA TYPE keyword.

@SamPaulIsaac Yes, I stuck here, How can I give query compatible for both. Is that possible?  Both have slight different syntax.

Can you share the query(one which causes this issue)?

@SamPaulIsaac I have plenty of files now I share few
I shared as link
Query

I've made the required changes here - https://rb.gy/vsp562 Looks like, the issue  is related to the keyword "datatype" which isn't supported in mysql, instead use "TYPE"  as it is compatible for both.

"Message    : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE TEXT' at line 1"
I tried your query, still I getting the same error.
any properties option there to make compatible.

For your query - "any property option to make it compatible" - yes we can, by using dialect configuration but again if you're using database migration scripts (Flyway/Liquibase) in a db/migration folder, the scripts must be compatible with the target database. Hibernate's dialect configuration handles the SQL generation for JPA entity mappings, but it does not directly modify or adapt raw SQL scripts located in your migration folders.

@SamPaulIsaac Ya I understand, I am using raw SQL query ,hence the conclusion is we can't make it compatible for both MYSQL and H2. right?

It is not guaranteed that using different databases you can use exactly the same scripts.
If your scripts are complex because they have strong use of advanced functionalities of a database, like special kind of indexes, tablespaces, data types, it is sure that your scripts could not be executed both in H2 and MySql.
Considering that you have three ways to handle it:

create very simple scripts not using any special feature of the database in a single directory and check that they can work on both databases
create two directories (one for H2 and one for MySql) and duplicate scripts adapting them for each db
mix the two solutions having a common directories for script that can be executed in both databases and one directory for each db with scripts that use advanced features of that db and that cannot be shared


This isnt possible. As soon as the queries become complex, you will run into issues.
You can separate them into different folders and point your tests to use the migration scripts according to the database vendor. You can have a folder for mysql migration files in /mysql and h2 files in /h2.
Using a different kind of database for your tests is also bad practice. I recommend using testcontainers as they will allow you to spin up docker containers during your tests, meaning you can have an instance of mysql that will run on test startup and shut down on test finish, hence eliminating the issue you are experiencing at the moment with the benefit of having meaningful  tests.
